# running ios instruments from command line

Tags: ios6, instruments, xcode-instruments

So far im only running instruments from instruments gui with a real iphone device.
And i have some Difficulties when try running it from Terminal command line shell.

the command im running is:
instruments -t myphone.trace -w mydidnumber myapplicationname -e Testcases.js -e results

the response of the command is:
Instruments Trace Error : (null)

Any help appriciated
Thanks

Comment: Is "myapplicationname" the fullpath to the app?